# RewriteCond & RewriteRule to correctly redirect and override the status of 301 in the .htaccess file

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have an Android app that loads a script **http://example.com/apps-support/ads/ads.php?appName=my_app** (`my_app` may change). My hosting provider made some changes on the server a few days ago and the above script began to return **301 Moved Permanently** status. Now, when I request my script it returns **301 Moved Permanently** status and then redirects to the root (**https://example.com?appName=my_app**). Why is redirection happening?
[image: 301 status]
[image: redirect to the root]
The logic in the Android app intercepts this redirection and try to open this URL (earlier, it works properly, because there were no redirections). The situation is aggravated by that fact that I don't have an ability to update the app to fix this issue (i.e., change **http** to **https**). My provider cannot fix this issue for some reason either. Thus, in my opinion, the only solution is to modify **.htaccess** file. So, I want the server to redirect my request to **https** and at the same time return (override) the status **200**, as shown below:
[image: proper redirection]
Is it possible?

My `.htaccess` file located in the root:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^appName=(.*)$
RewriteRule ^http://example.com/apps-support/ads/ads.php$ https://example.com/apps-support/ads/ads.php?%{QUERY_STRING} [R=301,L]
```

Unfortunately, it doens't work. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: "My hosting provider made some changes" - Are you saying that the hosting provider implemented a (broken) 301 redirect?! "Why is redirection happening?" - I don't see how we can answer that? "The logic in the Android app intercepts this redirection" - so this "redirection" was previously anticipated? But how do you "intercept" it? If it's a server-side redirect then your script is probably bypassed entirely? You need to find out where that redirect is occuring - ask your host? (Although I've never come across a hosting provider that would implement a redirect like this without warning?)

Answer (score 0):

Finally, my hosting provider helped me to solve this issue. I had to modify my `.htaccess` file like below:

```
RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} !^443$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/apps-support/ads/ads.php1$
RewriteRule (.*) https://example.com/$1 [L,R=301]
```

Now everything works as expected.